# In the context of machine learning, at what stage is the normalization process implemented?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, normalization, standardization

I have several data types and I want to use them as features for binary classification task.
The data is as follows:

1- Genes: I have several datasets containing bulk RNA-seq data. Some of these datasets have already undergone normalization through TPM (Transcripts Per Million) normalization, while others are still in their raw form. Additionally, a few datasets have been normalized using unconventional methods. I plan to merge all these datasets into a single dataset and then select only 20 features from the pool of 11,000. Since the data has been sourced from different places, and because some datasets have undergone different normalization processes, I intend to perform upper quantile normalization to bring all samples to the same scale. My question is: Should I perform this normalization before splitting the data into training and testing sets? Alternatively, should I first split the data into training and testing sets and then perform the upper quantile normalization separately on each set?
Another thought is to perform the upper quantile normalization for each data set separatly (there are 30 data set approximately) and only then I combine them and split the data to training set and testing set. There are just too many options I don't know which one is statistically correct. Morover, should I apply **batch effect correction** (cause of different data sets as source)?

2- Deconvolution: I am utilizing the dataset of genes I mentioned (with 11,000 genes) to execute a deconvolution algorithm, which will yield scores for each sample. I am uncertain about the ideal timing for running the deconvolution process. Should I conduct this process before or after dividing the data? Alternatively, is it more effective to run the algorithm on each dataset separately, then merge them into a single dataset, and finally split it into different subsets?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should never let the testing set have an effect on the training set processing. For example, if you were going to run a PCA on your data, you [would run the PCA using training data only](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55718/pca-and-the-train-test-split). Then, you would use the PCA components found with the training set to transform both the training set and the testing set, but it's important that the testing set is not used to estimate the PCA components.

Similarly, in your case what I would recommend is to get the normalization terms using the training set only, and then use them to normalize both the training and the testing set. I'm not sure how the deconvolution procedure works, but similar rule applies, don't let the testing set have any effect on how you process the training set.

I would guess that you will probably see some effect of data source, and that may want to correct for that, which is what you mention with batch correction I think. What you do would probably depend on your data and problem, so I don't know what to suggest here. However, I think that the cleanest thing, keeping to the principle above, would be to separate training and testing in each batch, and do the processing so that within each batch, the correction parameters are obtained from training data only (although you'd apply the same parameters to the testing set).

From what you say, there is some pre-processing that already comes from the data sources, where training and testing were both used to do the pre processing. This violates the principle above, I would think. But that doesn't necessarily mean that the analysis is not valid, there's only so much one can do with real data. One way to maybe circumvent this, though, is to use a whole batch of data (i.e. one data source) as testing only, and the rest as training.

Comment: Btw. After looking at your previous questions, I will note that if you see an answer that solves your problem, you should accept it as the correct answer.