# Number of principal components when preprocessing using PCA in caret package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca, cross-validation, caret

I am using the `caret` package in `R` for training of binary SVM classifiers. For reduction of features I am preprocessing with PCA using the built in feature `preProc=c("pca")` when calling `train()`.  Here are my questions:

1. How does caret select principal components?
2. Is there a fixed number of principal components that is selected?
3. Are principal components selected by some amount of explained variance (e.g. 80%)?
4. How can I set the number of principal components used for classification?
5. (I understand that PCA should be part of the outer cross-validation to allow reliable prediction estimates.) Should PCA also be implemented in the inner cross-validation cycle (parameter estimation)?
6. How does caret implement PCA in the cross-validation?

Comment: Useful information can be found in this post on [PCA and k-fold cross-validation in caret package in R](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46216/pca-and-k-fold-cross-validation-in-caret-package-in-r).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, caret keeps the components that explain 95% of the variance.
But you can change it by using the `thresh` parameter.

```r
# Example
preProcess(training, method = "pca", thresh = 0.8)
```

You can also set a particular number of components by setting the `pcaComp` parameter.

```r
# Example
preProcess(training, method = "pca", pcaComp = 7)
```

If you use both parameters, `pcaComp` has precedence over `thresh`.

Please see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-77/topics/preProcess

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken

Comment: corrected the link