# How does Caret's PCA function work?

Tags: r, pca, caret

I've been reading through this question: [PCA and k-fold cross-validation in caret package in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46216/pca-and-k-fold-cross-validation-in-caret-package-in-r) . In one of the answers, it was suggested to do PCA within the train function rather than before.
However, I tested both methods locally and saw no real difference in performance. What exactly is the logic behind this assumption?
This is added just for context:

```
 getTrainPerf(pca_train_svm)
  TrainAccuracy TrainKappa    method
1     0.8024293  0.5831657 svmLinear
> #PCA right way
> pca_train_svm<-train(Survived~.,data=newtrain_imp,method="svmLinear",trControl=control,
+                      metric=metric,preProcess=c("pca"))
> getTrainPerf(pca_train_svm)
  TrainAccuracy TrainKappa    method
1     0.8036165  0.5863854 svmLinear
```

Comment: See this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55718 for the general discussion of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would also love to understand what is really going on that is specific to caret.

Comment: if it is specific to caret package then the question is more relevant to Stack Overflow which addresses coding, including statistical coding.